# Suggest logic with one loop to concatenate two strings without strcat

Tags: c++, string, strcat

I have written a program to [concatenate two strings without using strcat](http://fahad-cprogramming.blogspot.com/2015/10/concatenate-two-strings-without-strcat.html) using two while loops for beginners. Need your suggestion to code it with one loop. Kindly share your logic thanks

Comment: Please provide the program in question rather than a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

```c
char first[1000];
char second[2000];
char result[4000];

void concat(char *first, char *second, char *result){
  int str_selector = 0;
  int i = 0, result_pos = 0;
  char *current_str = first;
  while(1){
    if(str_selector == 1 && current_str[i] == '\0'){
      result[result_pos] = '\0';
      break;
    }

    if(str_selector == 0)
      current_str = first;
    else
      current_str = second;

    if(current_str[i] != '\0'){
      result[result_pos] = current_str[i];
      result_pos++;
      i++;
    }
    else{
      i = 0;
      str_selector = 1;
    }
  }
}
```